# Get DNS-Admin with PHP

Tags: php, dns, soa

When looking at http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=www.example.com, you get a "DNS admin". How can I request this information from a php-script?

Answer (score 1):

Best option would probably be to get dns records directly:

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("example.com", DNS_SOA);
$admin = preg_replace('/\./', '@', $result[0]['rname'], 1); //need to replace the first dot with "@" because the rname is passed with dots and doesn't include "@"
echo $admin; //will output hostmaster@icann.org
?>
```

Read about php's [dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) function.

Comment: FWIW this is a better answer than mine. Had no idea there was a `dns_get_record` method!

Comment: I'm currently using a solution like this one, but I'm afraid that I could extract an email like some.email.company.com and it would translate it as some@email.company.com :/

Comment: Not sure how viable this solution is but you could try and ping the subdomain variations and check for status codes e.g. if email.company.com returns a 404 try pinging company.com if that returns 200 then company.com is the domain and some.email is the email account. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Netcraft has well-formatted data that they pull, likely, from DNS records. Unfortunately, the DNS records themselves are not so regular (or Netcraft wouldn't be needed).

What you're doing sounds kind of nefarious, but perhaps try using a system command like whois then search for the email address.

```
<?php 
$domain = 'cnn.com';
$results = shell_exec( "whois {$domain}" );
//parse results here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

dWhenever you want to scrape content with php, [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is your friend.

Simple example of usage below:

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer))
{
    print "Unable to fetch data.";
}
else
{
    print $buffer;
}
?>
```

Of course, you will need to parse the results of the fetch and extract whatever you need.

Hope that helps, good-luck!

***UPDATE:*** Not sure if the op wanted to fetch results from a webpage, or straight from a dns querying tool (dig, whois, etc.. ). This post will be deleted if I understood wrong.